# DropdownMenu value does not change

Tags: flutter, datatable

I created a function which adds DataRows to a List. Inside one of the cells, I am using a DropdownMenu, but the value does not get shown in the DataTable..
The besetzungsList.add(valueChoose) function gets executed.

```
_addAufgabe() {
    if (aufgabe.text.isNotEmpty || zeit.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {});

      for (var i = 0; i < currentValue; i++) {
        aufgabenList.add(aufgabe.text);
        zeitList.add(zeit.text);
        dataTableRows.add(
          DataRow(
            cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text(aufgabe.text),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text(zeit.text),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              DataCell(
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: valueChoose,
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  items: listItem.map((dynamic valueItem) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: valueItem,
                      child: Text(valueItem),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      valueChoose = newValue;

                      besetzungsList.add(valueChoose);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  aufgabe.clear();
    zeit.clear();
    return dataTableRows;
  }
```

Inside the DataTable Widget, I execute the function within the rows parameter.

```
        DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text("Aufgabe")),
            DataColumn(label: Text("Zeit")),
            DataColumn(label: Text("Besetzung")),
          ],
          rows: _addAufgabe(),
        ),
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: try to return `dataTableRows` from `_addAufgabe()`. Right now your function is not returning anything

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a part of the function. I edited my Question.actually I am returning it.